# Interval Probability given mixed CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was reviewing for an exam and got the following question :

Consider the following mixed distribution : 
$$ 
F(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       0 &\quad\text{if x}\le 1\\
       0.13 &\quad\text{if }1\leq \text{x}\lt 2\\
       0.33 &\quad\text{if }2\leq \text{x}\lt 3\\
       0.5 &\quad\text{if }x = 3\\
       0.5 + \frac{1}{4}(x-3) &\quad\text{if }3\lt \text{x}\lt 5\\
       1 &\quad\text{if x}\gt 5\\
     \end{cases}
$$

1. $P((−\infty,3))$?
2. $P([2,3))$?

The result for the first problem is 0.5 but I cant understand why, here is my reasoning :
$$
P((-\infty,3)) = F(3) - F(-\infty) - P(X=3) = F(3) - F(-\infty) -(F(3) -F(3^-)) = 
$$
$$
F(3^-) - F(-\infty) = 0.33 - 0 = 0.33
$$

For the second one the result is 0.17 yet i get : 
$$
P([2,3)) = F(3) - F(2) + P(X=2) - P(X=3) = 
$$
$$
F(3) - F(2) +(F(2)-F(2^-)) - (F(3) -F(3^-)) = 
$$
$$
F(3^-) - F(2^-) = 0.33 - 0.13 = 0.2 
$$

Am I doing things wrong?

Comment: I would agree with you.  On the other hand, $0.5=\mathbb P(\,X \in (-\infty,3]\,)$ and $0.17=\mathbb P(\,X \in (2,3]\,)$

Comment: @Henry Did you mean $0.17 = \mathbb P(X = 3)$?

Comment: @Henry Ok so best guess they provided the wrong solution?

Comment: @LucaGrignani I think $\mathbb P(\,X \in (2,3]\,) = \mathbb P( 2 \lt X \le 3) = \mathbb P( X = 3) = 0.5-0.33=0.17$.  So either the suggested result is wrong or the question is wrong with the shape of its brackets (or you transcribed it wrongly)

Comment: @Henry I'm sure about the transcription, thanks for your time!